# loop through using variables in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a requirement in which I gettext from a site and then later on use that in a loop so it can continue to click elements base on that variable. This works but only loops for 5 times and the number of times it should click is like 100 and or above. here is a sample of the code

```
String vText= driver.findElement(By.xpath(")).getText();
System.out.println(vText);
int vEle= vText.length(); 
for (int i=0; i<vEle; i++){
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("")).click();
```

What am I doing wrong please help me out

Thanks, 
Mediha

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking?  It is hard to tell what kind of answer you are looking for.

Comment: You are just looping it till the length of the Text. So I believe the length is only so much that the loop ends after 5 minutes.

Comment: You have syntax errors in your code `String vText= driver.findElement(By.xpath(")).getText();` has no closing quote. It would also be nice to see what the contents of `vText` are and what you expect it to have instead.

Comment: Are you really looping through a number of elements based on the *length* of the string you get back in vText?

Answer (score 2):

You might need to verify locators from where you are taking text 100 times. If it is same for all 100 elements it would work.

Have you tried with **findElements** method?

```
//It will return the List of webelements which has same locator
List<WebElement> elements=driver.findElements(By.xpath(""));

//Now iterate through List and do the required operation with each individual element
for(WebElement ele:element)
{
    ele.getText();   //It will print innertext of each element
    ele.click();     //It will click on each element
}
```

Comment: @Madi This pattern is almost always the most reliable, if you are trying to locate a number of elements with similar positions in the DOM. You can often make it an even more powerful pattern using relative xpaths, if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the error in your example is in this line:

```
int vEle= vText.length();
```

And later on your loop is:

```
for (int i=0; i<vEle; i++){
```

Which means youl loop is going to happen only that many times as the text is long. So if the text was `Hello` then the loop will happen only 5 times.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Santosh and Pavel,

I actually found another approach although I will look in to the code you sent me Santosh. But here is the code I came up with and please give me comments as to if is this the best approach.

```
String vText driver.findElement(By.xpath("")).getText();

//This will split the output from the slash and the output looks like 1/120
final String[] splitted = vText.split("\\D+");

//Here it will parse that output to an integer type and start with the first location
final int slideCount = Integer.parseInt(splitted[1]);

for (int i=0; i<slideCount; i++) {
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("")).click(); 
}
```

Comment: I'm fairly sure if you had stated in your original question that `vText` would have an expected appearance of `1/120` and you were hoping to loop for the number of times for the number following the "/" you would have got a far more concise answer, faster.

Comment: It's hard to know whether it's the best approach, without seeing the html you're trying to find elements in.